# How to use stacked autoencoders for pretraining

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

Let's say I wish to used stacked autoencoders as a pretraining step.

Let's say my full autoencoder is 40-30-10-30-40.

My steps are:

1. Train a 40-30-40 using the original 40 features data set in both input and output layers.
2. Using the trained encoder part only of the above i.e. 40-30 encoder, derive a new 30 feature representation of the original 40 features.
3. Train a 30-10-30 using the new 30 features data set (derived in step 2) in both input and output layers.
4. Take the trained encoder from step 1 ,40-30, and feed it into the encoder from step 3,30-10, giving a 40-30-10 encoder.
5. Take the 40-30-10 encoder from step 4 and use it as the input the NN.

a) Is that correct?

b) Do I freeze the weights in the 40-30-10 encoder when training the NN which would be the same as pregenerating the 10 feature representation from the original 40 feature data set and training on the new 10 feature representation data set.

PS. I already have a question out asking about whether I need to tie the weights of the encoder and decoder

Comment: Pretraining with autoencoders, training those layer by layer and using weight tying are all mostly outdated techniques. You are essentially wasting your time by using them. Just train the whole network or the whole autoencoder right away.

Comment: Yes - ReLU and dropout should be sufficient

Comment: Thank both of you.  When you say "Just train the whole network or the whole autoencoder right away", by "the whole network" do you mean train 40-30-10-NN and by "whole autoencoder" do you mean 40-30-10-30-40?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) Is that correct?

This is one of the typical approaches. You could also try to fit the autoencoder directly, as "raw" autoencoder with that many layers should be possible to fit right away, As an alternative you might consider fitting stacked denoising autoencoders instead, which might benefit more from "stacked" training.

> b) Do I freeze the weights in the 40-30-10 encoder when training the NN which would be the same as pregenerating the 10 feature representation from the original 40 feature data set and training on the new 10 feature representation data set.

When you train whole NN you do not freeze anything. Pretraining is only a kind of preconditioning for the optimization process - you show your method where to start, but you do not want to limit the fitting procedure of actual supervised learning.

> PS. I already have a question out asking about whether I need to tie the weights of the encoder and decoder

No, you do not have to tie weights, especially that you actually throw away your decoder  anyway. Tieing the weights is important for some more probabilistic models in order to make minimization procedure possible (like in the case of RBMs), but for autoencoder there is no point.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  It helped me better understand.